# What is mach_absolute_time based on on iPhone

Tags: iphone, timer

I use this code to keep track of last reboot:

```
+ (float) secondsSinceLastReboot{
     return ((float)(mach_absolute_time())) * ((float)timebase.numer) / ((float)timebase.denom) / 1000000000.0f;
}
```

I assumed mach_absolute_time() was based on last device boot time like it is on a mac. It doesn't seem to be based on that.  I actually have no idea what it is based on.

Look at the following behaviour (today's date is **2009-09-20**):

```
lastRebootTime = [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:-[self secondsSinceLastReboot]];
//last Reboot Time will contain : 2009-09-20 07:42:14 +0100
```

I'm absolutely certain I did not reboot my device at that time. My device hasn't been booted in a week.

Furthermore, when I unhook my device from the cable and run this app , it seems that when the device goes to sleep, the lastRebootTime starts shifting in the future. It seems `mach_absolute_time` doesn't keep account for sleep time. Or am i wrong about this?

I would really like to be able to get a timestamp from when the device last rebooted.  Any idea's?

Comment: you can #include "CAHostTimeBase.h" from CoreAudio Utility Classes see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1643/_index.html

Answer (score 56):

Had some trouble with this myself.  There isn't a lot of good documentation, so I went with experimentation.  Here's what I was able to determine:

mach_absolute_time depends on the processor of the device.  It returns ticks since the device was last rebooted (otherwise known as uptime).  In order to get it in a human readable form, you have to modify it by the result from mach_timebase_info (a ratio), which will return billionth of seconds (or nanoseconds).  To make this more usable I use a function like the one below:

```
#include <mach/mach_time.h>

int getUptimeInMilliseconds()
{
    const int64_t kOneMillion = 1000 * 1000;
    static mach_timebase_info_data_t s_timebase_info;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        (void) mach_timebase_info(&s_timebase_info);
    });

    // mach_absolute_time() returns billionth of seconds,
    // so divide by one million to get milliseconds
    return (int)((mach_absolute_time() * s_timebase_info.numer) / (kOneMillion * s_timebase_info.denom));
}
```

Comment: It looks like your experimentation resulted in the same solution arrived at by Apple's engineers.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html

Comment: Fwiw the latter appears to be for OSX.

Comment: This function works incorrectly for iOS. In return string you make integer value calculation. Since on iPhone 5 s_timebase_info.numer = 125 and s_timebase_info.denom = 3 finally you can get the same uptime during about 40 seconds between requests. Multiply mach_absolute_time() by float 1.0 for correctness.

Comment: In my test this function will not count when iOS is in sleep. See the accepted answer for this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488481/getting-ios-system-uptime-that-doesnt-pause-when-asleep

Answer (score 9):

If you don't care a lot about computation time you can use simple Obj-C class from Foundation

```
NSTimeInterval systemUptime = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime];
```

Comment: what do you mean by "completion time"?

Comment: Sorry for misspell, "computation time". I mean that obj-c works a bit slowly than pure C-code.

Comment: i use this code for check this in simulator but can't get the difference, after restart the simulator both systemUptime same..

Comment: @g212gs Note that it is system uptime! simulator's system - OSX. So you get right answer - the same uptime until you reboot you mac

Answer (score 3):

In case someone needs it in Swift (works in 4.2 & 5.0).

```
let beginTime = mach_absolute_time()

// do something...

var baseInfo = mach_timebase_info_data_t(numer: 0, denom: 0)
if mach_timebase_info(&baseInfo) == KERN_SUCCESS {
    let finiTime = mach_absolute_time()
    
    let nano = (finiTime - beginTime) * UInt64(baseInfo.numer) / UInt64(baseInfo.denom)
}
```

Comment: You can now use `clock_gettime_nsec_np(CLOCK_UPTIME_RAW)` to get the time in nanoseconds in one call. Also, if you want it **including sleep time**, you can use `clock_gettime_nsec_np(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW)`