# How retrieve ticks with same format like DateTime.Ticks in C++ ATL/MFC

Tags: c++, .net, mfc, atl

Is It possible get ticks number with same format like [`DateTime.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) .NET object, that is in 100ns units, in C++ ATL or MFC?

Comment: Add 0x701ce1722770000L to the FILETIME to change the bias from the year 1600 to the year 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DateTime.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) does not have any implications on timer resolution, so you are not promised that timer is 100ns accurate. In C++ you have a similar value using:

```
ULONGLONG nTicks = GetTickCount() * 10000i64;
```

If you need a more accurate timer, look for `QueryPerformanceCounter` based implementation. See:

- [How to use QueryPerformanceCounter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter)
- [Fastest timing resolution system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162826/fastest-timing-resolution-system)
- [Can someone decipher whether timeGetTime() or QueryPerformanceCounter/QueryPerformanceFrequency has lower overhead or/and accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407779/can-someone-decipher-whether-timegettime-or-queryperformancecounter-queryperfo)

UPD. As for alignment to that from .NET `Ticks` property, see comment from Hans above - value casted/calculated from result of `GetFileTime` API is also in the same 100 ns units and is set off `Ticks` property by a fixed constant.

Comment: according MSDN GetTickCount() returning ticks count since the system was started. there is ability get ticks since '01/01/0001 00:00:00' like in .NET?

Comment: `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx gets you time in `FILETIME` structure, then you add its values into single 64-bit integer, you add hardcoded constant (see above) and this is what you need.