# How to get iOS reboot times?

Tags: ios, unix, reboot

The reboot times means when user reboot device, reboot times will accumulate one.

So, is there a way that I can get the reboot times of an iOS device?

Comment: very odd requirement, but im sure iOS devices dont keep a record of this (for developers to access at least)

Comment: @Fonix I tried `sysctl -A | grep reboot` but get noting output on my mac.

Comment: `sysctl -A | grep boot` I can see the last boot time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this method, you can get the time since the system has last rebooted.

```
+ (time_t)getTimeSinceLastBoot {
    struct timeval boottime;
    int mib[2] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME};
    size_t size = sizeof(boottime);
    time_t now;
    time_t uptime = -1;
    (void)time(&now);

    if (sysctl(mib, 2, &boottime, &size, NULL, 0) != -1 && boottime.tv_sec != 0)
    {
        uptime = now - boottime.tv_sec;
    }
    return uptime;
}
```

To get the exact date, you could use the above method as :

```
    long totalSeconds = [self getTimeSinceLastBoot];
    NSDate *dateNow = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-totalSeconds sinceDate:dateNow];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

By using the above method, you could save the times to somewhere in persistent storage at regular intervals and check every time, If you get the same time next time, that means the device hasn't rebooted. If you get different time, then simply add that time to your database.

Don't forget to include the below files :

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

Comment: @Tim By using the above method, you could save the times to somewhere in persistent storage at regular intervals and check everytime, If you get the same time next time, that means the device hasnt rebooted. If you get different time, then simply add that time to your database.

Comment: Nice Way! If there is no direct solution to get the times, then save it   and check will be another way! You should put this into answer!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can find reboot time interval by this approach.

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime]
```

I found a healthy discussion at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937564/how-to-get-nstimeinterval-value-from-last-boot) thread.

Comment: Thank you, but not I need, what I need is reboot times not time actually.