# Getting more accurate time measurement

Tags: objective-c, time, nsdatecomponents

Currently I'm recording the time between two events in decimal minutes using :

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents =  [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];

CGFloat hour = [dateComponents hour];
CGFloat minute = [dateComponents minute];
CGFloat second = [dateComponents second];

//set start time in decimal minutes
CGFloat startTime = ((hour*3600.0)+(minute*60.0)+(second))*.016666;

//do work...

//set end time in decimal minutes
CGFloat endTime = ((hour*3600.0)+(minute*60.0)+(second))*.016666;

//calculate time elapsed in decimal minutes
CGFloat totalTime = endTime-startTime;
```

The issue that I'm having is that I am really only getting the time in seconds and then converting to decimal minutes. So, the only values that I'm getting are `0.016663` (one second in decimal minutes), `0.033325` (two seconds in decimal minutes), `0.049988` (three seconds in decimal minutes), etc. I'm not getting any values in between. Is there any way I can get a more accurate time? I checked to see if `NSDateComponents` has a `millisecond` property or whatnot, but I couldnt find any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use [CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/Reference/reference.html) which returns a double containing time in seconds and fractions of a second:

```
CFAbsoluteTime startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

Then later you can compute an elapsed time in seconds and fractions of a second:

```
elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime;

NSLog(@"Elapsed Time: %0.3f seconds", elapsed);
```

I like to have debug code (#ifdef DEBUG) in my app delegate and in viewDidAppear in my first view controller to report the elapsed startup time so I can keep an eye on that while developing.

Comment: In Apple's [presentation on app performance at WWDC 2012](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_235__ios_app_performance_responsiveness.pdf), they recommend saving the app start time in `main`, and then logging the diff in a `dispatch_get_main_queue` block inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. I like your `viewDidAppear` solution better though :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use NSDate?

```
NSDate *date1, *date2;
NSTimeInterval timeInSeconds;

date1 = [NSDate date];

// Do work

date2 = [NSDate date];
timeInSeconds = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

// Or, without using date2:

timeInSeconds = -[date1 timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

That should give your measurement sub-second accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get Unix-y, you can use `gettimeofday` ([reference](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/High_002dResolution-Calendar.html)):

```
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
NSLog(@"seconds: %d, microseconds: %d\n", tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec);
```

Be sure to add `#import <sys/time.h>` to your file

Answer (score 0):

Or if you really want to get down the metal, you can use `mach_absolute_time()`, as per this [SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450737/what-is-mach-absolute-time-based-on-on-iphone) and/or [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html).