# iPhone timer with minimal error/drift

Tags: iphone, timer, nstimer

I'm looking to create functionality that gets repeated very quickly - around 50ms. I need, however, as much consistency as possible in the call and I have found NSTimer to be a bit erratic. It seems I might find some help with keeping time from [mach_absolute_time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450737/what-is-mach-absolute-time-based-on-on-iphone). Any tips on using this to create an extremely accurate timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at GCD, specifically `dispatch_source_create()`?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_source_create

Comment: That's a good call, I haven't had a lot of GCD experience but there is a section on timers on [this doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html) which seem to give a pretty accurate alternative to NSTimer. Thanks.